# Quantity of members of sealed class in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Is there any way to get quantity of members of `sealed class` in Kotlin? 
For example, for this class it will be 2:

```
sealed class Foo {
    object Bar : Foo()
    data class Baz(val m: String) : Foo()
}
```

Comment: Why not just hardcode it? It's not like you can change it at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [KClass.nestedClasses](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/nested-classes.html) of the kotlin reflection api. This returns all classes declared in the given class (so eg. the companion object is listed too).

```
fun countSubclasses(clazz: KClass<*>): Int =
        clazz.nestedClasses.filter {
            it.isSubclassOf(clazz)
        }.size
```

To call this function use

```
countSubClasses(Foo::class)
```

For detailed information see [kotlin reflection reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html).

Comment: have no compile-time possibilities for doing that emerged? :(

Answer (score 1):

The `nestedClasses` property of `KClass` should be fine:

```
println(Foo::class.nestedClasses.size) //2
```